# Constructing $\delta$ to show Chevalley-Eilenberg complex $\Lambda \mathfrak g \otimes \mathcal U\mathfrak g \rightarrow k$ is null homotopic

Tags: homological-algebra, lie-algebras, lie-algebra-cohomology

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a finite dimensional Lie algebra over a field $k$ and $(\Lambda^\bullet \mathfrak g \otimes \mathcal U\mathfrak g, d)$ be the Chevalley-Eilenberg chain complex.

I would like to ask if there is an explanation on the map, preferably explicit map,

$\delta : \Lambda^k \mathfrak g \otimes \mathcal U \mathfrak g \rightarrow \Lambda^{k+1} \mathfrak g \otimes \mathcal U \mathfrak g$

such that

$d\circ \delta +\delta \circ d= id$.

There must be such a map $\delta$ because $\Lambda^\bullet \mathfrak g \otimes \mathcal U\mathfrak g\rightarrow k$ is an exact sequence. However, I am not sure if there is an explicit expression for such $\delta$.